# Moodle is representing grades 15% instead of showing it 100%

Tags: moodle, scorm1.2

First of all I am brand new to Moodle. We have a SCORM course that we imported in Moodle. The course have 15 questions in the end. If you answer all 15 questions correctly then it means your score is 100%. But when we complete the course the info tab shows 15% instead of 100%.

[image]

What configuration do I make that `Grade for attempt` and `Grade reported` show `100%` instead of `15%` ?

Thanks

**********EDIT*************************

Actually we have two courses. For one course it shows 100% and for other course it is showing 15%. What is happening for course showing 100%, it send `cmi.core.score.raw` 100 and `cmi.core.score.max` 100. Here is the screen shot

[image]

But for other course if all questions are answer right then it sets`cmi.core.score.raw` 15 and `cmi.core.score.max` 15. And moodle shows 15%. But if 4 questions are answer right right then it sets `cmi.core.score.raw` 4 and `cmi.core.score.max` 15.

[image]

For 4 answers right

[image]

and finally this is the result of moodle

[image]

So I think we have to set actual score as `cmi.core.score.raw` and `cmi.core.score.max`. In this way moodle will show the correct percentages. like in case of 4 answers right 27% and incase of all right 100%.

I don't know if there is any settings for this in moodle. These are my findings till yet.

Thanks

Comment: If you upload the course to SCORM Cloud and turn on debugging, can you see exactly what data is being sent by the course to the LMS?

Comment: @AndrewDownes check my edit

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of this sentence "So I think we have to set actual score as cmi.core.score.raw and cmi.core.score.max."

Comment: I can't find a concrete answer for you, but here's the line of code in Moodle where those grades are getting put together. Maybe you can figure something out in the PHP: https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/fd57d685c785ac2900098b0aea87556d4696fa84/mod/scorm/locallib.php#L1217

Comment: I mean how many questions are correct Moodle show it as `Grade for attempt`. Like if all 15 questions are correct then at that time `cmi.core.score.raw` is `15` and Moodle shows it as `Grade for attempt : 15%`. If 4 questions are correct then `cmi.core.score.raw` is 4 and Moodle show it as `Grade for attempt : 4%`. `Grade reported` is total number of questions. Like in this course I have 15 questions so `cmi.core.score.max` is 15 and Moodle shows it as `Grade reported : 15%`.  ...continued

Comment: ....Actual score is what student gets actually. Like 100 or 27. if all questions are correct then actual score becomes 100 and if we set this 100 as `cmi.core.score.raw` and `cmi.core.score.max` then Moodel will show 100%. If 4 questions are correct then actualScore become 27 and if we set this 27 as `cmi.core.score.raw` and `cmi.core.score.max` then Moodel will show 27%. This is what I am trying to say. But I don't know whether this approach is right or not :)

Comment: That approach is OK. In later versions of SCORM you can use scaled score, but that's not an option in SCORM 1.2.

Comment: Ah. OK I will do it. Many thanks for your help  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your scorm activity setting and go to grade setting, and change maximum grade 100 to 15. Since you have 15 questions and each question is sending 1 score to lms, you have to change maximum grade setting according to score points you are sending to lms by scorm.

[image]